# How can I modify localStorage with Python?

Tags: python, browser, local-storage

I want to edit localStorage with Python but I am not sure how to do it.
I have found a library named localStoragePy but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: read documentation for `localSoragePy` or see its source code.

Comment: do you meas `localStorage` in web browser? It seems module `localStoragePy` is NOT for web browser. It is similar to `localStorage` in browser but it is for keeping data in own porgrams. I'm not sure but some browsers may keep data as file(s) with SQLite database and it may need only standard module `sqlite3`

Comment: I want to edit web browser localstorage

Comment: you should find folder with browser's settings for your profile and check files with extension `.sqlite` . On Linux my Firefox keeps my settings in `/home/furas/.mozilla/firefox/some-random-name-for-profile` and I see file `storage.sqlite`. Probably it can have it. I never tried to use this file but there is similar file `places.sqlite` and I used it to read my bookmarks. There is also folder `storage` which may also keep data for different URLs. Something similar should be for `Chrome` - it also use `sqlite` to keep some data.